# Gcloud PHP72 extension intl is missing

Tags: php, docker, gcloud

If I follow the following docs:
- https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/run-symfony-on-appengine-flexible

I have my app.yaml as following:

```
runtime: php
env: flex

runtime_config:
  document_root: web
  front_controller_file: app.php

env_variables:
  APP_ENV: "prod"
```

But I get the following error:

```
Step #1: Installing dependencies from lock file
Step #1: Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.
Step #1:
Step #1:   Problem 1
Step #1:     - Installation request for league/uri 5.3.0 -> satisfiable by league/uri[5.3.0].
Step #1:     - league/uri 5.3.0 requires ext-intl * -> the requested PHP extension intl is missing from your system.
Step #1:   Problem 2
Step #1:     - Installation request for league/uri-components 1.8.1 -> satisfiable by league/uri-components[1.8.1].
Step #1:     - league/uri-components 1.8.1 requires ext-intl * -> the requested PHP extension intl is missing from your system.
Step #1:   Problem 3
Step #1:     - Installation request for league/uri-hostname-parser 1.1.1 -> satisfiable by league/uri-hostname-parser[1.1.1].
Step #1:     - league/uri-hostname-parser 1.1.1 requires ext-intl * -> the requested PHP extension intl is missing from your system.
Step #1:   Problem 4
Step #1:     - Installation request for league/uri-manipulations 1.5.0 -> satisfiable by league/uri-manipulations[1.5.0].
Step #1:     - league/uri-manipulations 1.5.0 requires ext-intl * -> the requested PHP extension intl is missing from your system.
Step #1:   Problem 5
Step #1:     - Installation request for sylius/sylius v1.2.6 -> satisfiable by sylius/sylius[v1.2.6].
Step #1:     - sylius/sylius v1.2.6 requires ext-exif * -> the requested PHP extension exif is missing from your system.
Step #1:   Problem 6
Step #1:     - sylius/sylius v1.2.6 requires ext-exif * -> the requested PHP extension exif is missing from your system.
Step #1:     - stefandoorn/sitemap-plugin v1.0.10 requires sylius/sylius ^1.0 -> satisfiable by sylius/sylius[v1.2.6].
Step #1:     - Installation request for stefandoorn/sitemap-plugin v1.0.10 -> satisfiable by stefandoorn/sitemap-plugin[v1.0.10].
Step #1:
Step #1:   To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in your .ini files:
Step #1:     - /opt/php72/lib/php-cli.ini
Step #1:     - /opt/php72/lib/ext.enabled/ext-apcu-bc.ini
Step #1:     - /opt/php72/lib/ext.enabled/ext-mailparse.ini
Step #1:     - /opt/php72/lib/ext.enabled/ext-memcached.ini
Step #1:   You can also run `php --ini` inside terminal to see which files are used by PHP in CLI mode.
Step #1: The command '/bin/sh -c /build-scripts/composer.sh' returned a non-zero code: 2
Finished Step #1
```

But, according to the docs: (https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/php7/runtime) these extensions are enabled by defulat?

I have already tried to add a php.ini file to my root folder and putting the following inside it:

```
extension=intl.so
```

But that didn't work.

Comment: Depending on your system, you should install it via an installer IE (This is for Debian based systems) `sudo apt-get install php-intl`   Then don't forget to restart your web server IE `sudo service apache2 restart`

Comment: Also to view the extensions installed .. You can create a file IE `test.php` and simply put this inside: `<?php phpinfo(); ?>`

Comment: But isn't it my Gcloud that doesn't have those extensions? My local env. hasn't anything to do with it?

Comment: correct .. those extensions need to be installed at the server level